# Objective-C: How to tell if a class method allocs/inits in

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa

How can you tell if a class method allocs and inits an object?  For example...

```
NSArray *theArray = [NSArray array];
NSArray *anotherArray = [[NSarray alloc] init];
```

What is the difference between using these two?  Don't they both create an empty array?

```
NSCalendar *theCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSCalendar *anotherCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] init];
```

How do you know which to use when creating objects?

Comment: Comes down to following naming conventions and reading the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference if ARC is enabled.

[NSArray array] is a convenience method. It allocates an array object, initialises it and marks the object for autorelease (the later is when automatic reference counting is disabled). Many objects provide these type of methods to create instances. Consult API docs to find out if the class of your interest provides alloc-init-(autorelease) shortcut or if it has creation or initialisation methods suited better for your needs. Use them - they are shorter, code is easier to read, no need to worry about whether ARC is on or off. Write similar methods for your own classes.

Use specific alloc-init if you need to pass parameters in init function. E.g.

```
NSMutableArray ary = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:50];
```

or even better

```
NSMutableArray ary = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:50];
```

Again, alloc-init pair were useful before ARC when one wanted to have a control over the instance reference counting.